# What is the native, idiomatic, and safe way to store an i32 in a file?

Tags: file-io, rust, binary

I am looking to take something like an i32 (or any signed integer) and store it in a file. I am aware of serde, but I'm looking to understand how this could be done natively and safely.

The only solution I have come up with is manually calculating the binary and converting it to an array of u8s. Is this the way it needs to be done?

Comment: *I am aware of serde, but I'm looking to understand how this could be done natively and safely* -- I'm not sure whether you think serde is "not native" or "not safe", but I don't think either of those is the case. What do you mean by this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call [`to_be_bytes()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.i32.html#method.to_be_bytes) or [`to_le_bytes()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.i32.html#method.to_le_bytes) to convert it to big or little endian, respectively.

```
pub fn to_be_bytes(self) -> [u8; 4];
pub fn to_le_bytes(self) -> [u8; 4];
```

Comment: I will advice little endian because 99% of modern computer are little endian.

Answer (score 2):

Write it:

```
use std::{fs::File, io::Write};

fn main() {
    let mut f = File::create("/tmp/myfile").expect("unable to open file");
    write!(&mut f, "{}", 42).expect("unable to write file");
}
```